# What part of this RegEx is causing it to find no matches in IE7 and IE8?

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, compatibility

I've got a regex that looks for a `<span>` with the class name `foobar`. It works in IE9, Chrome and Firefox. It's failing in IE7 and IE8. Can anyone tell me why?

```
new RegExp( /(\s*?)<span\b(?:.*?)(?:class=(?:'|"|.*?\s)?foobar(?:\s|\3))(?:.*?)(?:\/)?>(.+?)<\/span>(\s*?)/g )
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping a regex literal with the regex constructor? Lose the `new RegExp(` and `)`, they're not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're applying the regex against html you got from getElementById().innerHTML or jQuery .html(), IE will uppercase the HTML tags which could be the problem. If you make the regex case-insensitive - that is, change the modifier `/g`  to `/gi` at the end - does that fix it ?

It seems like you're also mixing the regex literal and RegExp object syntax, you can do it with just the regex literal instead.

```
var regex = /(\s*?)<span\b(?:.*?)(?:class=(?:'|"|.*?\s)?foobar(?:\s|\3))(?:.*?)(?:\/)?>(.+?)<\/span>(\s*?)/gi;
```

Comment: +1 — IE 9 changed `innerHTML` and `outerHTML` to return HTML with lower-case node names, so I think you've hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Yesssirree. Great get. Many thanks. I often use the RegEx constructor  when I don't know the value of "foobar" in advance but in this case I do and your solution is a simplification. Thank you.